# html or javascript, how to find out where is the program files folder?

Tags: javascript, html, directory

i have some HTML files that i want to run in user local machine ( offline).
is there any method to find out in which **hard drive** the program files folder is located?

**Note:** do you know any methods that don't raise security problems.

Comment: Windows has a `%PROGRAMFILES%` variable.  Don't think JavaScript can access the user's environment variables though.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: No, not through standard-compliant Javascript.

Comment: i want to refer to a file that is inside the user program files folder i don't in which hard drive it is. i should say that the html file is saved inside the user hard drive.

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-think your approach.  There are ways to push/pull data but the only predictable way would be to access and environment variable you will not have access to from the sandbox.  IE specifically locks down the local machine zone down to prevent accessing the file system arbitrarily, you would need to do MOTW to avoid this, thereby restricting yourself more in other ways.  Still can't understand what you are actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: update your question with details of what you're trying to achieve - it's very unusual to need access to the programs folder (wouldn't work on mac or Linux or mobile devices) - is it a HTML Application .hta?

Comment: thank you web_bod. after reviewing your comments and given answers, i found out that my approach is bad, as Jeff said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is very confused. Not every computer has a "Program Files" directory or even the concept of drives because not every computer is Windows.

On top of that, HTML5 Offline Mode [just requires a manifest file to be hosted by your web server](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/html5_tutorial/offline_applications.html). The browser will put the cached data in the right place for it.

If you're talking about some internal deployment of a non-hosted page and want to spawn IE directly, I think it's a bad idea, but use the `%ProgramFiles%` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `file system api` in `HTML5` - have a look at the [draft documentation](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/#idl-def-FileSystem)

If you're calling `requestFileSystem()` for the first time, **new storage is created for your app**. It's important to remember that this file system is sandboxed, meaning one web app cannot access another app's files. This also means you cannot read/write files to an arbitrary folder on the user's hard drive (for example My Pictures, My Documents, etc.).

So if you're thinking about a web page being able to poke around a users program folder, then the answer is no, you'll need some kind of an app engine - e.g. [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/exploring_file_capabilities.html) or the Windows8 Metro apps.

Comment: ... which pretty much means you can't find the Program Files folder.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is no crossbrowser way of doing this. If it is ok for you to have an Internet Explorer only solution try to look at the ActiveX component called FileSystemObject and its GetSpecialFolder method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265315%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on Windows but it seems you can try something like this:

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
Response.write("ProgramFiles envioronment variable is set to:\n\n" + 
               WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%ProgramFiles%'));
```

Program Files are found on Environment Variables, so that's what you're looking for.

Regards,

PS: this will lead you to some security warnings. Actually, this is not safe.

Comment: Make sure he does this from an HTA or it will be hit by IE's Local Machine Lockdown Policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

Comment: Actually, I will encourage him to develop a .Net application or HTA, no just a collection of offline pages, because the kind of access granted here are very important.